# Build fails on Azure but not locally with c#10

Tags: c#, azure-devops

my project targets netstandard 2.0 and use c#10 and the next part fails only on Azure

```
namespace Xpand.Extensions.Tracing;
public interface IFileSystem {}
```

any workarounds? except of refactoring all my libs against c#9.0